# Laravel error when with method type when storing in database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a $request to Laravel function and store the data in a table and i get error

The API route

```
Route::post('/orderdetails/store/', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiOrderDetailController@store');
```

The Laravel function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'order_id' => 'required',
        'product_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $order_id = $request->order_id;
    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    $order_details = OrderDetail::create(['order_id' => $order_id, 'product_id' => $product_id]);

    $success = 'Order Details Confirmed Successfully';

    return response()->json($success);
}
```

what I send to Postman and the error I get

[image: The Error]

The api.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/subscribtions', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiSubscribtionController@index');



Route::post('/handle-login', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@handleLogin');
Route::post('/handle-register', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@handleRegister');

Route::get('/brands', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiBrandController@index');
Route::post('/add-brand', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiBrandController@store');

Route::post('/products/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@store');
Route::get('/products/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@delete');
Route::get('/brands/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiBrandController@delete');
Route::post('/brands/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiBrandController@update');
Route::post('/products/update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@update');
Route::get('/products/{brand?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@index');
Route::get('/products/arrivals', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@arrivals');
Route::get('/products/more/{brand}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@more');
Route::get('/products/show/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@show');

Route::post('/order/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiOrderController@store');
Route::post('/orderdetails/store/', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiOrderDetailController@store');


Route::middleware('is.admin')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/subscribtions/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiSubscribtionController@store');
    
    Route::post('/handle-logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@handleLogout');
});
```

Comment: try to add an extra header from postman `Accept: application/json`

Comment: it returned the error but in json view

Comment: check if there is any other route may over-write this one or any middleware make redirect for your request

Comment: no friend, it's the only route and its outside of any middleware

Comment: try to just return any thing from route without using controller first like this `Route::post('/orderdetails/store/', function(){   return 'foo';  });`

Comment: the same error in the photo in the post

Comment: so the problem is a routeing problem, not a controller problem if you could share your route file it would be helpful

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, I can see your postman URL looks odd. Unless you've changed something from `RouteServiceProvider.php` such as `prefix()` definition, or you have your project within `mobitech/public/your_project` your URL should be `http://localhost/mobitech/api/orderdetails/store`. Not sure why are you adding the `public` slug in it.

On the other hand, you should remove the `/` at the end of your endpoint in both route definition and postman.

Also please share your `api.php` route file to see if because of order priority your endpoint is being overwritten by another route.